# Create multi dimensional array from keys and levels

Tags: php

I have array like this

```
    {
        "name": "girl",
        "level": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "boy",
        "level": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "15-26",
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "27-38",
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "hit pedestrian",
        "level": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "intersection hit",
        "level": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "night",
        "level": 4
    },
```

I want to generate a new array looking like this

```
{'girl':
   {'15-26':
      {'hit pedestrian':
          {'night': 0
      },
      {'intersection hit':
          {'night': 0
      },
   },
   {'27-38':
      {'hit pedestrian':
          {'night': 0
      },
      {'intersection hit':
          {'night': 0
      },
   },
},
{'boy':
   {'15-26':
      {'hit pedestrian':
          {'night': 0
      },
      {'intersection hit':
          {'night': 0
      },
   },
   {'27-38':
      {'hit pedestrian':
          {'night': 0
      },
      {'intersection hit':
          {'night': 0
      },
   },
}
```

This is required output format for frontend.
(levels can go deep into almost level 20)

and also, how can I access index like

```
$arr['boy']['15-26']['hit pedestrian']['night']++;
```

if i have array like this to tell where to add

```
$plusOneAt = ['boy','15-26','hit pedestrian','night'];
```

I'm using Symfony if that helps.

edit: I have a working code for the first part now. Any way to optimize this?

```
$level = $level - 1; //deepest level from generating first array
$childArray = array(); 
for($i = $level; $i > 0; $i--) {
    foreach($pivotList as &$pl) {
        if($pl['level'] == $i) {
            $pivot[$pl['name']] = $i == $level ? 0 : $childArray;
        }
    }
    $childArray = $pivot;
    if($i > 1) $pivot = array();
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: I wish I can come up with something, but I really have no idea how to do it. If you don't want to write a code for me, telling me the idea of how to do it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Please check and follow the site guidelines when submitting a question in here

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I tried working from deepest level and work up from there. Seems working

```
$level = $level - 1; //deepest level from generating first array
$childArray = array(); 
    for($i = $level; $i > 0; $i--) {
        foreach($pivotList as &$pl) {
            if($pl['level'] == $i) {
                $pivot[$pl['name']] = $i == $level ? 0 : $childArray;
            }
        }
        $childArray = $pivot;
        if($i > 1) $pivot = array();
    }
```